# Get vector of columns with highest values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I'd like to be able to create a column vector whose values in each row correspond to the column in a matrix with the max value in that specific row.

For example,
If I have a matrix such as:

```
A = [1,5,2;3,1,1;0,1,0];
```

I'd end up with the matrix:

```
maxValueColumns = transpose([2,1,2]);
```

Is there an easy/efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`max()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html):

```
A = [1,5,2;3,1,1;0,1,0];
[~, maxValueColumns] = max(A, [], 2); % 'maxValueColumns' will contain [2; 1; 2]
```